# git stores wrong credentials everytime

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I have been granted pull/push rights of few repos of git. when i installed git for the first time, it asked for username and password. after that, i just used to write
`git checkout .`
`git pull --rebase`
but now since few time, git bash asks for credentials every time when i pull or push any file.

when i looked as windows credentials, i saw wrong password was saved. and it doesn't change even after editing. when i edit and save correct password, it get backs to it's previous state (wrong password).

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the credential helper user (type git config credential.helper), you should [remove the cached credentials from that helper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15381198/6309)

But make sure the local repository which is problematic does use an HTTPS URL

```
cd /path/to/existing/local/repository
git remote -v
```

If it does not start with HTTPS, then the issue would be different.